# Angularjs : color table cells dynamically

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to color the cells of my table according to their value.
This code doesn't work whereas it should as the division is < 1

### HTML

```
<td class="text-center col-md-1"
    ng-class="{'redCell': vivier.value1/vivier.value2<1}" >
    {{vivier.value1/vivier.value2}}
</td>
```

### CSS

```
.redCell {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Do you know why?

Comment: could you try in this way ng-class=" (vivier.value1 / vivier.value2) < 1 ? 'redCell' : ' ' "     ?

Answer (score 0):

You better should try like that:

```
<td class="text-center col-md-1" ng-class="{(vivier.value1/vivier.value2)<1 ? 'redCell' : 'normalCell'}" >{{vivier.value1/vivier.value2}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-class, you can use ng-style like this:

```
<td class="text-center col-md-1" ng-style="yourStyle">{{vivier.value1/vivier.value2}}</td>
```

then in file JS:

```
yourStyle = {"background-color": "red"}
```

It's just a sample. You can change any value as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td  class="text-center col-md-1" ng-class="{{vivier.value1/vivier.value2 < 1}}?'redCell':'otherCell'"> {{vivier.value1/vivier.value2 < 1}}</td>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http){

 $scope.vivier = {'value1': 4,'value2': 2};
  $scope.test ="test";
});
```

```css
.redCell {
    background-color: red;
}
.otherCell{
  background-color:yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" ng-app="MyApp" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HHS - Problems</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--<script src="scripts/bundle.public.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="scripts/DemoController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
 <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table>
<tr >
<td  class="text-center col-md-1" ng-class="{{vivier.value1/vivier.value2 < 1}}?'redCell':'otherCell'"> {{vivier.value1/vivier.value2 < 1}}</td>
  
  <td  class="text-center col-md-1" ng-class="{{vivier.value2/vivier.value1 < 1}}?'redCell':'otherCell'"> {{vivier.value2/vivier.value1 < 1}}</td>
  
</tr>

   </table>
</body>
</html>
```